# Get Word Settings Property From Code

Tags: c#, wpf, word-addins

I am developing a Word Add-In and I need to access from code the "Word Options". More specifically I want to see whenever the value of the "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" property is on or off.

I didn't try it to read from registry,I tried only from getting word interop services. But not succeeded.

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is for helping with problems of *existing* code, not writing some.... Have you tried google? It seems to me that this should be a simple registry entry somewhere..

Comment: Just a clarification here, the "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" is a property of the Word desktop application and not a property of the Word Document (the file itself). Please check your wording and make clear what the actual case is.

Comment: Which version of office are you using?

Answer (score 0):

As I said, the first google entry i found was this [one here](http://www.thewindowsbulletin.com/how-to-disable-hardware-graphics-acceleration-in-microsoft-office-2013-1517/).

You just have to look at the registry value of **DisableHardwareAcceleration** under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Graphics`.
The version key (`15.0`) might depend on the version of office you use.

I suggest you search first through `Office` and then choose the highest version you find.

Side note:

- value one (`1`) stands for disabled
- no key **and** zero (`0`) **both** stand for enabled/not disabled

Comment: There is no property for "DisableHardwareAcceleration" in registry unless we explicitly create in Graphics folder.Is that true?

Comment: @kamesh as I can see, the folder first/only gets created when a user disables *hardwAcc* via office itself. if there is no such key this stands for *not disabled*. so yes, this is true so.

Comment: as @ehh pointed out this option *might* only be available on **office 2010+**! but i'm not sure as powerpoint 2002 does already has a option called "use hardware acceleration"...

Comment: I did also read from registry but same result as you mentioned it is first created when disable the feature.So Any other solution we can try on this to read this property?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have this option on my MS Word 2007.
But what you can do is record a macro. 
You need to have the developer tab visible.

Record the macro, go to the option you need to check. Once done, you can edit the generated code under Macros button.
If there is a such option via code (check "Disable hardware graphics acceleration"), you will see how.

The generated code is in VBA, you will need to convert it to your appropriate language.

**Update:**

I recorded the macro on Word 2013 and no code was generated for it. There is no such option via code.

FYI, if you want to record a macro (according to Word 2013, may be very similar for other versions):

1. File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Main Tabs (Right side) -> Check Developer checkbox
2. In developer tab -> Record Macro -> Ok
3. Now, you are in record Mode, go to Word options -> Advanced -> Under Display, check/uncheck "Disable hardware graphics acceleration" checkbox.
4. In developer Tab, stop recording
5. Click on Macros -> Edit the recorded macro -> You may get a subroutine with some auto-generated code:

   ```
   Sub Macro1()
   '
   ' Macro1 Macro
   '
   '
   End Sub
   ```

This recorded macro doesn't show any code, this was recorded for the option you looked for.

Following an example of another recorded macro ("Optiomize character positioning for layout rather than readability" checkbox also in Word options->display):

```
Sub Macro2()
    '
    ' Macro2 Macro
    '
    '
    Options.PrecisePositioning = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please send me the details how to achieve this for some extent?

Comment: So this not gonna help right?Any other solution can we do for getting this property value,because I tried reading the registry value but that also not work for all word versions even that registry value is added newly only in 2010 when we first disabled "Hardware Acceleration" in word options. In word 2013 even that is not working.

Comment: Correct, through Word interop, as you can see, it is not possible. I tried on my PC with office 2013